# Is a strong retain cycle a relevant consideration for a singleton class that should exist for the life of an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a singleton class in my app that is created at app launch and always in use. I now am going to introduce an NSTimer that calls one of the singleton's methods periodically, so my understanding is that the timer will retain a strong reference to my singleton class (since the singleton class is the target). Is this correct? More importantly, is a strong retain cycle a problem for a singleton class that should live for the duration of the app? If so, why?

Comment: The fact that you are dealing with a singleton should be irrelevant. Use proper memory management no matter what.

Comment: Where do you think there is a retain cycle? Does the singleton have a reference to the timer?

Comment: If your singleton creates a repeating timer that invokes a method of your singleton, and the singleton keeps a strong reference to the timer, then yes, you have a retain cycle. However, it's really only an academic concern, since your singleton persists for the life of your app. Retain cycles are bad if they cause objects to persist in memory after all other references to them are released.

Comment: If you use one of the scheduledTimer methods that adds the timer to the event loop all in one call, you can make the instance variable that holds the timer weak. Then when you invalidate the timer it will automatically be deallocated.  That will break the retain cycle. Also make your singleton invalidate your timer as part of it's dealloc call.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a reference cycle affects two or more objects. So it's not just the singleton but also one or more other objects too.

Answer (score 3):

You ask:

> I have a singleton class in my app that is created at app launch and always in use. I now am going to introduce an `NSTimer` that calls one of the singleton's methods periodically, so my understanding is that the timer will retain a strong reference to my singleton class (since the singleton class is the target). Is this correct?

Yes, `NSTimer` will maintain a strong reference to that instance of the singleton class. This strong reference is maintained until you `invalidate` the timer (or in the case of a non-repeating timer, until the timer fires).

> More importantly, is a strong retain cycle a problem for a singleton class that should live for the duration of the app? If so, why?

The fact that a scheduled `NSTimer` instance maintains a strong reference to the target of its handler is not a problem, per se. You just have to be aware of this fact and manage your memory appropriately. All this means is that if you're done with some object that is a target of the `NSTimer`, that you are responsible for manually calling `invalidate` of that timer.

The only time that this strong reference to the timer's handler becomes problematic is when you're dealing with some object that that is of a more transitory nature (e.g. a view controller that might later be dismissed). Too often people think "oh, I'll just `invalidate` that `NSTimer` in the `dealloc`" method, but that doesn't work. The Objective-C `dealloc` method (as well as the Swift `deinit` method) is not called until there are no more strong references, so you can't try to resolve that timer's strong reference in `dealloc`, because `dealloc` can't get called until the timer is invalidated. Instead if you're done with the target of a `NSTimer`, you must manually `invalidate` the timer (e.g. in the case of the view controller example, people frequently do that in `viewDidDisappear`).

In your case, the fact that you have a scheduled repeating timer, calling the singleton method is not a problem. Just be aware that this singleton object (which will likely never fall out of scope anyway) cannot be deallocated as long as the scheduled `NSTimer` is still active. You'd have to `invalidate` the `NSTimer` in order to resolve the timer's strong reference to that target.

---

Two additional observations:

1. You've described this `NSTimer` behavior as a strong reference cycle (retain cycle). Technically, this isn't a strong reference cycle, but rather just a fact that a schedule `NSTimer` is retained by the run loop on which it's scheduled, and then the timer then retains the target upon which its handler is scheduled.

   This is an somewhat academic distinction (because it manifests itself much like a strong reference cycle), but it's worth noting.
2. You should also be aware that instead of using a `NSTimer`, you can also use a GCD dispatch source timer. So, create a timer property in the class:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t timer;
   ```

   And then instantiate and start the timer:

   ```
   typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
   self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
   dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0);
   dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
       [weakSelf handleTimer];
   });
   dispatch_resume(self.timer);
   ```

   This pattern, unlike the `NSTimer` approach, does not retain the target of the timer (or, in this case, the object upon which we're referencing via `self`) because of the use of `weakSelf` pattern in the block (which resolves any strong reference cycle). Thus we end up in a timer that is safely released when the object that contains it is deallocated, with no strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider it a problem. A singleton class is already hard to refactor and reuse. Adding a retain cycle to one is going to make the class that much harder to change or reuse in the future. When you discover that you need this class (or at least the set of responsibilities this timer is a part of) to not be a singleton you'll also need to remember or identify this memory leak and fix it as part of your refactor. Future you will probably be sad.

Instead you can write a class which follows good patterns (for memory management and otherwise) regardless of if it is accessed as a singleton or not. In your case that might mean keeping a weak reference to the timer ("[Note in particular that run loops maintain strong references to their timers, so you don’t have to maintain your own strong reference to a timer after you have added it to a run loop.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/)") and invalidating that timer if this object is deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

The retain cycle might not be problematic at this time as you're using a singleton that doesn't need deallocation, but what if in the future someone else refactors the singleton into a regular class?

Another consideration is that `NSTimer`'s are not very energy efficient, and Apple [warmly recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MinimizeTimerUse.html) switching to `GCD` sources for performing timer-related tasks. You might even be able to break the retain cycle via `weak` references with this approach.